# Weird menu jumping on my computer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, malware

I've noticed that my start menu, notification bar and right mouse menu activate on their own, in a very random manner; I haven't figured out what would be triggering it, or been able to intentionally reproduce it. This happens when I'm browsing the web, watching a movie, or just doing some document editing. This has happened maybe about a dozen times over the past year.
I'm certain that I'm not touching any keypad buttons or touchpad that could trigger this. I have scanned it with Malwarebytes and Avira AV and all comes back clean. The system has the latest updates as well.

What could this be then?

Comment: Update BIOS, Power and Video Drivers.  Restart when done. If you have a mouse driver now reinstall that. Also (important at this point) try a different mouse.

Comment: do you have a wireless receiver plugged in? If it's not your own mouse in your bag causing the issue, maybe interference from other devices is being interpreted as valid instructions by the (in this case a very badly designed) wireless receiver...

Comment: @QuickishFM no, just touchpad

Comment: Macro recorder scripts? Autoit, autohotkey, jitbit, do-it-again, sendkeys?

Comment: @somebadhat no, I've got none of these on my machine.

I've had another instance of this today, and managed to get a video of it:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q63yDtOXtZgHG0juu1miHcSf8Xjv3eXo

Any better idea with this now?

Comment: @John I'm yet to try that; just as I was about to, the lockdown was announced and don't want to get stuck with a corrupted machine when all of the repair shops are closed

Comment: @John Also I've had another instance of this today, and managed to get a video of it, to which I've pasted the link in the comment before the last one.

Comment: I watched that. You need to try a new mouse. Use Amazon for this and they will deliver it to you.

Comment: @John I've got a wireless mouse which I'm using on my work computer, so I can try that one, but currently I'm using just the touchpad.

Also I've noticed, that the video compression software cut off 2/3 of the video, so here's the original one in full length:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ejyk0sK_D0r_U2CyF8dIKtdRAjqP-L1B

Comment: I see pretty much the same behaviour. Please let us know about the wireless mouse.

Comment: @John what I'm struggling to understand is the pattern of this behavior: if this is connected to the mouse as you say, then why is there nothing for weeks, or months, and then it occurs all of a sudden? IMHO if it is a mouse defect then this should be a consistent not a sporadic behavior.

Comment: I had asked you nearly two months ago to update BIOS, Power and Video drivers but you have not responded to that so I assume all else was well. If not the mouse, do the updates and then please let us know.

Comment: The window sliding in from the right is your notification window yes? What is the window on the left?

Comment: @somebadhat the start menu.

Comment: @John yes, while it's true that I could've been more responsive with this, I've explained above that the lockdown intervened.

Comment: The blue window on the left is your Start Menu?

Comment: @somebadhat sorry, you're right, that's actually the window that pops up if you click into the text search box right next to the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit.

Three things:

1. Install and learn how to use Microsoft's [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). When menu jumping occurs drag and drop the explorer bullseye onto the window to find what process opened the window.
2. Get familiar with what a normal Task Manager window looks like for you. Take a screenshot of it. Create a shortcut on your desktop to output your tasklist to file. Run it when menu jumping occurs. `tasklist /nh | sort> menuJumpTasklist.txt`.  Create a base tasklist: `tasklist /nh | sort> baseTasklist.txt`
3. Could it be a poorly written push notification?

Disable push notifications system wide.  If that solves your problem you can enable push notifications then track down which browser push notification is causing the problem.

Disable push notifications:

[image: disable push notifications in Windows 10]

Open the Start menu and click the Settings icon. Navigate to System - Notifications & actions. Scroll down to the Notifications section and disable "Get notifications from apps and other senders" **and / or** “Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows” option.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy here (one that I use) and given the situation that has unfolded is to do a Windows 10 Repair Install. From the Media Creation link, choose the second option (download) and run in place. At the appropriate spot, choose Keep Everything. This reinstall Windows, all drivers and fixes problems.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Then, if you still have issues, back everything up, run again and then Keep Nothing.